# Lumen Reportable & Renderable Exception doesn't work

Tags: laravel, exception, lumen

I am trying to define a custom renderable exception exactly as shown in the documentation [example](https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#renderable-exceptions) but when I throw my custom exception, the render and report functions inside the exception class are totally ignored.

I am aware that I can handle my custom exceptions inside the exception handler but this is something I would prefer to do inside the exception class.

Is it something more that I should do to register the exception in order for the render and report functions to be called? What am I missing?

Thank you!

**EDIT**: I'm using Lumen 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this feature is not available in Lumen framework, only in Laravel. Lumen's documentation is very misleading as it lets one to imagine that the features concerning errors are common in Laravel and Lumen.

In any case, currently in Lumen only exception handling inside the exception handler is available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it feature will be added in one of next 5.8.* releases.
PR: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/pull/958